# In treeview, unable to set data as root when ParentID is present but parent's isActive condition is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview, hierarchy

I have successfully implemented the treeview of data in MVC
But I have one problem with isActive condition, i.e.

- I am taking the one with null ParentID as root node... that is fine but
- I also want to take one that has ParentID with the parent isActive 
  condition is false as root node

[image]

Here  ID-1 will become Root as it has NULL ParentID , but I also want ID-3 as root as its parent(ID-2) isActive is false

Here is my code:

Model:

```
 public class AcList
    {
        public long? ParentID{ get; set; }
        public IList<Account> AccountList{ get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Account> accounts = db.Accounts.Where(f => f.isActive).ToList();
    AcList acList = new AcList(){ ParentID = null, AccountList = accounts };
    return View(acList);
}
```

**_partialTree.cshtml**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Typ</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (Model.AccountList.Where(s => s.ParentID == Model.ParentID).Any())
    {
        foreach (Account node in Model.AccountList)
        {
            if(node.ParentID == Model.ParentID)
            {
                AcList inner = new AcList 
                               { 
                                   ParentID = node.ID, 
                                   AccountList = Model.AccountList 
                               };
                <tr>
                    <td>@node.Description </td>
                    <td>@node.Typ</td>
                </tr>
                List<Account> ac = ViewBag.AccountList as List<Account>;
                        var child = ac.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(node.ID)).Count();

                if (child > 0)//if it has sub Accounts
                {
                          @* Recursive Call for Populating Child-items here*@
                           <tr class="panel">
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    @Html.Partial("_partialTree", inner)
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                }
             }
          }
      }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How exactly can i achieve this?

Comment: where exactly do you make the null check?

Comment: thanks @AGuyCalledGerald for your reply... Acually I am Passing ParentID as null from controller, I have just edited my controller